# Applications throwing an error "quit unexpectedly" on Mac OSX Catalina running on MacBook Pro 5,5 (Mid 2009)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, error

1. Info: I have a problem on Mac OSX Catalina running on my MacBook Pro (Mid 2009 / Model Identifier 5,5). Every time any application is opened (for example Google Chrome), I get an error "Google Chrome quit unexpectedly". Click report to see detailed information and send a report to Apple - with Ignore & Report buttons."
2. Info: However, after I dismiss the error notification clicking "Ignore" button, and re-open the application, the application opens and functions normally
3. Info: This happens for the first time with with any application I try to open
4. Question-1: Why does this happen ?
5. Question-2: How do I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Choose Report and examine the information sent to Apple.

Comment: An 09 Macbook isn't qualified to run Catalina, so you're running it on unsupported hardware - a very long way unsupported. Rolling back to El Capitan might help. You might even get away with High Sierra, but anything later needs Metal2, which a GeForce 9600 is definitely not capable of.